Is there a way to change the Next JS scroll restoration target in the project config?
In my Next.JS project, page scroll behavior occurs in the <main> element, not in the <body> element. This is due to a stylistic choice, but I believe this is preventing the expected scroll restoration behavior. Is there a way to direct next to apply scroll restoration to the <main> element instead of the <body> element?
next: 14.1.3
